# Replicated cache with NON_XA transaction fails to syncronize cache data upon Wildfly v.21 (same with v.22) second cluster node start

Tags: java, wildfly, infinispan, wildfly-21

Works perfectly on Wildlfy v.18  (Infinispan 9.4.16) but not on v.21 or v.22 (Infinispan 11.04)

A standard Wildfly v.22 (same with v.21) configuration using standalone-full-ha.xml running as a cluster of two nodes.

Cache is configured as:

```
<cache-container name="opencell">
    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
    <replicated-cache name="opencell-cft-cache" statistics-enabled="true">
        <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
    </replicated-cache>
</cache-container>
```

Cache is accessed this way:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/cache/opencell/opencell-cft-cache")
private Cache<CacheKeyStr, Map<String, CustomFieldTemplate>> cftsByAppliesTo;
```

Java version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)

Infinispan fails to synchronize caches when starting a second cluster node because of missing transaction.

Changing transaction to NONE, a second cluster node starts with no errors.

```
16:13:46,141 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (thread-18,ejb,opencell-node2) ISPN000136: Error executing command PutKeyValueCommand on Cache 'opencell-cft-cache', writing keys [/JobInstance_GenericWorkflowJob]: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: javax.transaction.InvalidTransactionException: WFTXN0002: Transaction is not a supported instance: TransactionImpl{xid=Xid{formatId=2, globalTransactionId=0000000000000001,branchQualifier=0000000000000001}, status=ACTIVE}
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionTable.enlist(TransactionTable.java:227)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.TxInterceptor.enlist(TxInterceptor.java:423)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.TxInterceptor.handleWriteCommand(TxInterceptor.java:387)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.TxInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(TxInterceptor.java:227)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.statetransfer.TransactionSynchronizerInterceptor.visitCommand(TransactionSynchronizerInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndHandle(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:190)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleTxWriteCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:259)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleWriteCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:249)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndFinally(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheMgmtInterceptor.updateStoreStatistics(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:249)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:210)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndExceptionally(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor.visitCommand(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:49)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.invokeAsync(AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.java:226)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl.invokePut(StateConsumerImpl.java:739)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl.doApplyState(StateConsumerImpl.java:676)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl.applyChunk(StateConsumerImpl.java:644)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl.applyStateIteration(StateConsumerImpl.java:618)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl.applyState(StateConsumerImpl.java:597)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.commands.statetransfer.StateResponseCommand.invokeAsync(StateResponseCommand.java:80)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BasePerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.invokeCommand(BasePerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.java:115)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BaseBlockingRunnable.invoke(BaseBlockingRunnable.java:100)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BaseBlockingRunnable.lambda$runAsync$0(BaseBlockingRunnable.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:883)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2251)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BaseBlockingRunnable.runAsync(BaseBlockingRunnable.java:74)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BaseBlockingRunnable.run(BaseBlockingRunnable.java:41)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BasePerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.handleRunnable(BasePerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.java:163)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.TxPerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.handle(TxPerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.java:89)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.GlobalInboundInvocationHandler.handleCacheRpcCommand(GlobalInboundInvocationHandler.java:167)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.GlobalInboundInvocationHandler.handleFromCluster(GlobalInboundInvocationHandler.java:113)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processRequest(JGroupsTransport.java:1378)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processMessage(JGroupsTransport.java:1302)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.access$300(JGroupsTransport.java:131)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport$ChannelCallbacks.up(JGroupsTransport.java:1445)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:784)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.fork.ForkProtocolStack.up(ForkProtocolStack.java:135)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:306)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FORK.up(FORK.java:142)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG3.up(FRAG3.java:160)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:351)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:359)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:868)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:243)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.deliverMessage(UNICAST3.java:1049)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.addMessage(UNICAST3.java:772)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.handleDataReceived(UNICAST3.java:753)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:405)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:592)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:132)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FailureDetection.up(FailureDetection.java:186)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:254)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE3.up(MERGE3.java:281)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:300)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1385)
    at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.util.SubmitToThreadPool$SingleMessageHandler.run(SubmitToThreadPool.java:87)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@21.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextReferenceExecutor.execute(ContextReferenceExecutor.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@21.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextualExecutor$1.run(ContextualExecutor.java:70)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.transaction.InvalidTransactionException: WFTXN0002: Transaction is not a supported instance: TransactionImpl{xid=Xid{formatId=2, globalTransactionId=0000000000000001,branchQualifier=0000000000000001}, status=ACTIVE}
    at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.13.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.ContextTransactionManager.resume(ContextTransactionManager.java:148)
    at org.infinispan@11.0.4.Final//org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionTable.enlist(TransactionTable.java:219)
    ... 71 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug. Created: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-12798

Thanks for the report.